# Typescript file cannot find the declarations defined in .d.ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I'm trying to declare some global window functions for my typescript plugin. The functions are defined in the browser and i want them to be declared in the code aswell.

For some odd reason my code cant find those declarations from that file. The declarations are in @types/globals.d.ts file.

Do i need to configure the tsconfig.json file or something like that. Cant seem to find a straight answer from anywhere else.

Just in case, here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "strict": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

**globals.d.ts**

[image]

**index.ts**

[image]

Here's the error message

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't set TypeScript definition files somewhere else than in a "sibling" file (same directory, same name, .d.ts extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct solution was to redefine the window interface. Now the rest of the files automatically detect the types.

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    section: string;
    __t: (string: string) => string;
    apiSessionKey: string;
    companyData: CompanyData;
    conf_dateformat: string;
    country: string;
    customerCode: string;
    decimalSymbol: string;
    employeeEmail: string;
    employeeID: number;
    employeeName: string;
    formAttributes: any[];
    gdprFeaturesEnabled: boolean;
    isExistingRecord: boolean;
    page_lang: string;
    priceDecimals: number;
    recordID: number;
    subsection: string;
    thousandsSeparator: string;
    userGroupID: number;
    userGroupName: string;
    userID: number;
    userName: string;
  }
}
```